# jQuery expand all and collapse all with inspinia

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Inspinia theme.

[An example page](http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.4/form_basic.html)

If you click the `fa-chevron` icon in the upper right of each ibox, it collapses the ibox.

I want to collapse all the iboxes with a collapse all button. And then expand them all with an expand all button.

The buttons look like:

```
<button type="button" data-action="expand-all" class="btn btn-white btn-sm">Expand All</button>
<button type="button" data-action="collapse-all" class="btn btn-white btn-sm">Collapse All</button>
```

I want clicking `"Collapse All"`, to, in-effect, click all of the minimize panel buttons.

How?

Comment: just click view-source on the link provided

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what version you are using, but for the AngularJS implementation in `directives.js` you can see the function `iboxTools` that handles this. If you just want to use jQuery to manually do it it's as simple as:

```
//slide up (or down) all ibox content
$('div.ibox-content').slideUp();

//change the chevron
$('.ibox-tools a.collapse-link i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down');
```